# why my prepared statement, whose ? count and array values look correct can't seem to actually insert into the table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to figure out why my prepared statement, whose `?` count and array values look correct can't seem to actually insert into the table?

The Key/Position listing is truncated, but for some reason the values are binding as empty strings or null...

```
$sth->debugDumpParams();

SQL: [152] INSERT INTO tablename (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?)
Params:  10
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
.
.
.
```

- The array I am trying to insert in  `$sth->execute($obj);` looks correct in a `print_r` after that statement.
- Is there a way to deeper debug why this did not yield an error or actually insert?

Answer (score -1):

`$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`